# How can I make some table columns editable with Symfony2 forms?

Tags: symfony

I'm learning how to use Symfony and found the form model useful. I'm having some problems with special cases, like having a table showing an entity and only some columns show as input. What's a good way of doing this? I don't see how to mix the entity values with the form.

Comment: That table only will contain one entity or a collection of entities for been created/edited?

Comment: A collection of entities for edition. I only want to be able to edit a couple of properties and show most of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the underlying object value of the form element through vars.value

E.g. (as per [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template))

```
{{ form.vars.value.task }}

{{ form.task.vars.full_name }}
```

And so on.

This means you can render out object values alongside your form elements without creating any inputs other than the ones you need in your form.

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks!